# Ribbon script is running correctly always but on first try

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a custom Close Opportunity script which is complete replica of CRM's default opps.js with exception that it has couple lines of code that I've wrote. I replaced default Close Opportunity ribbon buttons with my own and made everything work as it should work. There's one little problem I can't understand though.

I'm using VPN and remote desktop connection when I'm developing in this particular case. Everytime I open VPN and connect to the remote desktop, then open CRM and then click my Close Opportunity ribbon button my script wont work. Opportunity is closed correctly, but my custom logic is not run. If I reactivate the opportunity and close it again or in addition close another opportunity everything works just fine. I can't repeat this problem in any other way than just closing remote desktop and disconnecting VPN and then connecting again.

But that should not have nothing to do with how CRM works right? Or is there some cache or something I'm not aware of but which could cause this problem? Anyway, I'm keeping myself busy with this but any advices are welcome.

Edit: And I have tried to clear Internet Explorer's cache etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see an example of the code?

Also when calling a webresource from the ribbon remember to reference using "$"

Example $webresource:SomeScript.js